# Relate child to parent on view dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models, Usermodel and Measurements model. The Measurements model is related to the Usermodel via a ForeignKey relationship. I have successfully created the form to allow create users, but would like that when you view these users, you can from there create measurements without indicating the relationship, as it should automatically use the Usermodel being currently displayed as the instance and relate it. This has been an issue. I tried writing the view like this..

## View.py

```
def client_measurements(request, pk):
    measurement = UserModel.objects.get(id=pk)
    measurements = measurement.measurements_set.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MeasurementsIForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.client_name.client_name = measurement.client_name
            measure = form.save(commit=False)
            measure.instance = measurement
            measure.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('client', args=   [measurement.id]))
    else:
        form = MeasurementsIForm()
    return render(request, 'app/measurements.html', {'form':form,      'measurements': measurements, 'measurement': measurement})
```

This doesn’t save to database. I am new to django, please what am I doing wrong?

## Model.py

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
# client_lname = CapitalizeCharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
MALE = 'Male'
FEMALE = 'Female'

sex = (
    (MALE, 'Male'),
    (FEMALE, 'Female'),

)

client_gender = models.CharField(
    max_length=100,
    choices=sex,
    null=True

)
tel = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.client_name

image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload, null=True, blank=True)


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.image:
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.width > 800 or img.height > 534:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('client', kwargs={'pk': self.id})


class Measurements(models.Model):
user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
client_name = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

DRESS = 'Dress'
SHIRT = 'Shirt'
TOUSERS = 'Trousers'
SKIRT = 'Skirt'
ATIRE = 'Native Atire'
GOWN = 'Gown'

dress_type = (
    (DRESS, 'Dress'),
    (SHIRT, 'Shirt'),
    (TOUSERS, 'Trousers'),
    (SKIRT, 'Skirt'),
    (ATIRE, 'Atire'),
    (GOWN, 'Gown'),

)

cloth_type = models.CharField(
    max_length=100,
    choices=dress_type,
    null=True

)

neck = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
over_bust = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
bust = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
under_bust = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
chest = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
crutch_depth = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
ankle = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
inseam = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
total_height = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
waist = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
hips = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
neck_to_heel = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
neck_to_above_knee = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
above_knee_to_ankle = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
arm_length = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
trouser_length = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
shoulder_seem = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
arm_hole = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
bicep = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
fore_arm = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
wrist = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
v_neck_cut = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
shoulder_to_waist = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
waist_to_above_knee = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], blank=True, null=True)
comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
measurement_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=measurement_image_upload, null=True, blank=True)
```

## Form.py

```
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
client_name = forms.RegexField(regex=re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]+((\s[A-Z]([a-z]+)?)?)((\s[A-Z]([a-z]+)?)?)'), required=True, error_messages={'invalid': "Each name must be Capitalized. E.g 'Kelly Roland' not 'kelly roland'"}, label="Client's Full Name")
tel = forms.RegexField(regex=re.compile(r'(080|090|070|081)[0-9]{8}'), required=False, error_messages={'invalid': "Enter a valid phone number"}, label="Phone No")
class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    widgets = {
        "tel": TextInput(),
        "client_name": TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Emanuel Felix Johnson"})
    }
    labels = {
        "client_name": "Client's FullName",
        "tel": "Phone No",
        "client_gender": "Gender"
    }

    fields = ('client_name', 'client_gender', 'address', 'tel', 'image' )

class MeasurementsIForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Measurements
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['user_name', 'client_name']
```

Comment: Please include your models and `MeasurementsIForm`.

Comment: class MeasurementsIForm(forms.ModelForm):
           class Meta:
                model = Measurements
                fields = '__all__'
                exclude = ['user_name', 'client_name'].

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't get the form code to display like a the initial code. Please pardon me..

Comment: Please include your models in the question as well.

Comment: I have updated the question with all the necessary information you may need. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked this code again, and using the previous answer, I managed to get it to work. I don’t know why it didn’t work previously, as this was how I initially did it.

## New View

```
@login_required
def client_measurements(request, pk):
    client = UserModel.objects.get(id=pk)
    measurements = client.measurements_set.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MeasurementsUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            measurement = form.save(commit=False)
            measurement.user_name = request.user
            measurement.client_name = client
            measurement.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('client', args=   [client.id]))
else:
    form = MeasurementsUpdateForm()
return render(request, 'app/measurements.html', {'form':form, 'measurements': measurements, 'client': client})
```

If there is a better solution for this, I would love to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd change your view to do what you want. Note, the template context now has the client key being user rather than `measurement`.

```
def client_measurements(request, pk):
    client = UserModel.objects.prefetch_related('measurements_set').get(id=pk)
    measurements = client.measurements_set.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MeasurementsIForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            measurement = form.save(commit=False)
            measurement.client_name = client
            measurement.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('client', args=   [measurement.id]))
    else:
        form = MeasurementsIForm()
    return render(request, 'app/measurements.html', {'form':form,      'measurements': measurements, 'client': client})
```

As an aside, I highly recommend changing your Measurements model to:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The ForeignKey properties should be named so that the represent the related models instance, not a property of them. When using an ORM you should take advantage of the abstractions rather than fight against them.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I tried this, but i get another error.  "  

UserModel matching query does not exist."